# Enumerate within a definition

Tags: enumerate, theorems, newtheorem

I have a macro that is used for math definitions, which adds a line-break after the word 'Definition', it works well except when I start a definition with an enumeration. Is there a way to add a line-break in this case?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{TheoStyle}
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec
  \makeatother
\theoremstyle{TheoStyle}
\theoremstyle{TheoStyle}

\newtheorem*{defn*}{Definition}

\begin{document}
  \begin{defn*}
      A new definition
  \end{defn*}

  \begin{defn*}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{defn*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\mbox{}` to start a paragraph and then backup with `\vspace`.

```
  \begin{defn*}
    \mbox{}\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{TheoStyle}
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec
  \makeatother
\theoremstyle{TheoStyle}
\theoremstyle{TheoStyle}

\newtheorem*{defn*}{Definition}

\begin{document}
  \begin{defn*}
      A new definition
  \end{defn*}

  \begin{defn*}

\mbox{}\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\topsep}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{defn*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i see you've tried to make the item labels roman, but they're still italic.  `\upshape' should do the job.  (package `upshape' is part of one of the ams collections; i've forgotten whether that's `amsmath` or `amsclass`, but in any case, it's included in a tex live distribution.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the note. Here, `\roman` is the command for typesetting the counter (like `\arabic` and `\alph`), not for changing the typeface, so I think that the result is essentially what the OP intended.

Comment: That's correct, `\roman` was for roman-numerals in the enumeration labels (i) vs (1). Ingenious answer btw.