# How to write to the right of "Definition" and also enumerate within the definition?

Tags: enumerate, theorems, newtheorem, definition

The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359136/enumerate-within-a-definition) shows how to enumerate within a definition. But what if I want to also write something to the right of **Definition**?

For example,

**Definition.** Let G be a group.

(i) ....

(ii) ....

How to implement this?

Comment: Well, just use  an enumerate environment after `Let G be a group`. Or do I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: @Bernard It shows up under "Definition", not to the right of it.

Comment: Oh! You don't want the labels near the left margin?

Comment: @Bernard I want to keep (i), (ii), ... where they are, but I want "Let G be a group" to be to the right of "Definition". In other words, I want the final result look as in my example above. If I just type "aaa", then "aaa" appears below "Definition", and the final result does not look as in the example from my question.

Comment: It seems your link provides a layout for definitions with a line break after the word ‘Definition’ and its label. Why don't you use the standard definition style?

Comment: To enlarge on what @Bernard says, the purpose of that question was to explicitly break to a new line after "Definition"; that's what the `\mbox{}` does.  Don't use the `\mbox{}`, or, rather, use it *only* when you want "Definition" on a line by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should be close to what your desired output looks like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
  Let G be a group.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item first
    \item second
  \end{enumerate}
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```